# addition chains for products of relatively prime factors

Tags: co.combinatorics

Suppose I have a set $F$ consisting of relatively prime factors (e.g. $\{ 5, 7, 9, 13, 17 \}$) and the set $P = \{\prod_{f \neq f_i}f \} $ consisting of the products of N-1 factors in $F$ (e.g. $\{13923, 9945, 7735, 5355, 4095\}$).

Is there a special structure in these numbers that would allow writing a short addition chain? I'm looking into Pippenger's algorithm as described in [Daniel Bernstein's paper](http://cr.yp.to/papers/pippenger.pdf) but it doesn't seem to take advantage of the redundancy in this case.

Comment: Suitable on cstheory perhaps?

Comment: A short addition chain for what?  Do you want to generate the products additively, or are you given the products and want to make something else?  Note that the set of n numbers can be generated using less than 3n multiplications and no divisions, if you are concerned about speed.

Comment: "Do you want to generate the products additively": Yes. This is for raising powers, so there's no shortcuts.